# Query to see if subscription is active between two date ranges

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table that stores seasonal address dates:

addressStartDate, addressEndDate

I'm trying to find people whose seasonal addresses were historically active in May, but I'm not quite sure how to format it. I just can't seem to conceptualize how to build the query based on the two date fields. The "was active" part is the part I'm having issues with.

The years for the dates in this case are all stored as 1000, since the seasonal address switch happens at the same time every year. So what I'm looking for is people whose addresses were active between DATE '1000-05-01' and DATE '1000-05-31' - I hope this suffices to describe my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE addressStartDate >= '1000-05-01' 
AND addressEndDate <= '1000-05-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE addressStartDate <= ? AND addressEndDate <= ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
SELECT addressStartDate, addressEndDate, otherfields
FROM yourTable
WHERE addressStartDate >= '1000-05-01'
   AND addressEndDate < '1000-06-01'
```

Or depending on the interpretation of your question, if an address date just needs to exist in the month, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT addressStartDate, addressEndDate, otherfields
FROM yourTable
WHERE addressStartDate < '1000-06-01'
   AND addressEndDate >= '1000-05-01'
```

Depending on how you're storing your data (with or without time), instead of using `BETWEEN`, I prefer using >= and < as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want active for the whole month of May, then:

```
select *
from t
where t.StartDate <= date('1000-05-01') and t.StopDate >= date('1000-05-31')
```

If you want active for any days in May:

```
select *
from t
where t.StartDate <= date('1000-05-31') and t.StopDate >= date('1000-05-01')
```

The `StopDate` limits may be off by one, depending on whether or not the date of the stop date is considered an active date.

This may also be complicated by whether your data goes by the calendar year, because you have a problem with your data structure.  `StartDate` can be larger than `StopDate`, which would imply a year wrap. To handle year wraps, try this:

```
select *
from t
where (t.StartDate < t.StopDate and t.StartDate <= date('1000-05-01') and t.StopDate >= date('1000-05-31')) or
      (t.StartDate > t.StopDate and ( t.StartDate <= date('1000-05-01') or t.StopDate >= date('1000-05-31')))
```